# Matrix of linear map from non-standard basis to standard

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Assume that the matrix of a linear map $T:V→V, V= P_1(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is
$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -1 \\
12 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$
with $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,4)^T,(1,3)^T\}$

Find the matrix of this map with respect to the standard basis:

---

Why is the result not $B^{-1}*M*B$?

How is the formula derived?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [IT]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = [TI]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = [T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} \Rightarrow [T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}
\end{align*}

At your case, you have $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,4),(1,3)\}$, $\mathcal{B}' = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}$. Since
\begin{align*}
[I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
4 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow [I]_{\mathcal{B'}}^{\mathcal{B}} = ([I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'})^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1\\
4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

It remains to calculate $[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = [I]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}[T]_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}}[I]_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}$. Can you take it from here?